# How to find the inverted condition probability

Tags: probability

Whenever I get this question, I have a hard time with it.

An example of a problem:

In the fall, the weather in the evening is *dry* on 40% of the days, *rainy*
on 58% of days and *snowy* 2% of the days.

At noon you notice clouds in the sky.

Clouds appear
at noon on 10% of the days that have **dry evenings**,

25% of the days that have **rainy evenings**,

and
35% of the days that have **snowy evenings**.

From that I get:

$P(S)$ = "prob. snows" = $.02$

$P(R)$ = "prob. rains" = $.58$

$P(D)$ = "prob. is dry" = $.40$

$P(C|S)$ = "prob. that it is cloudy given that it snows" = $.35$

$P(C|R)$ = "prob. that it is cloudy given that it rains" = $.25$

$P(C|D)$ = "prob. that it is cloudy given that it is dry" = $.10$

However, the question given is:

Find the probability of snow in the evening given that you saw clouds at noon.

I interpret this as:

$$P(S|C)$$

I can't get it right. Is there a formula to it without having P(C)?

Comment: I must be interpreting the problem incorrectly. I'll edit my question.

Comment: can you write the question to know if you interpreted it correctly as $P(S|C)$ ?

Comment: Yes. Just finished editing the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P\left(S \mid C \right) = \dfrac{P\left(C \mid S \right)P\left(S\right)}{P\left(C\right)} =  \dfrac{P\left(C \mid S \right)P\left(S\right)}{P(C|S)P(S)+P(C|D)P(D)+P(C|R)P(R)}$.

Comment: Oh I see. P(C) has to be found by adding the probabilities. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for [Bayes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem), which states

$$P(S\mid C) = \frac{P(C \mid S) \, P(S)}{P(C)}$$

But you need $P(C)$ too.

Comment: The issue is that I don't have C. I only have the P("cloudy given snow)

Comment: Then $P(S\mid C)$ is not determined, since you can choose any value (in $(0,1]$) for $P(C)$.

Answer (score 1):

Using Bayes' Theorem and the law of total probability: $P(S | C) = 0.0365$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $P\left(S \mid C \right) = \dfrac{P\left(C \mid S \right)P\left(S\right)}{P\left(C\right)}$.